# LOWERING Bitmap Quality Produces OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, networking, graphics, bitmap

I'm trying to capture the user's entire desktop as an image. I do this in the following way:

```
        public Bitmap CaptureScreen()
    {
        // Set up a bitmap of the correct size
        Bitmap CapturedImage = new Bitmap((int)SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width,
            (int)SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        // Create a graphics object from it
        System.Drawing.Size size = new System.Drawing.Size((int)SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width, (int)SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height);

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(CapturedImage))
        {
            // copy the entire screen to the bitmap
            g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0,
                size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
        }
        return CapturedImage;
    }
```

However, if I try to change the `PixelFormat` from `Format32bppArgb` to `Format16bppArgb1555`, it produces an `OutOfMemoryException`, which I don't really understand, considering I've lowered the quality.

Any ideas? Or how can I reduce the quality of this image (as it will be being sent over the network at quite frequent intervals)

Comment: *When* does the OOM occur? I would imagine it was during a conversion, not the end-result.

Comment: It happens at the line

`using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(CapturedImage))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fromimage(VS.100).aspx): (also [related](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/536050/graphics-fromimage-outofmemoryexception))

> This [`FromImage()`] method also throws an exception if the image has
>   any of the following pixel formats.
>
> - Undefined
> - DontCare
> - Format16bppArgb1555
> - Format16bppGrayScale

In the "related" link, msdn goes on to say that:

> The only issue here is that OutOfMessageException is not very accurate exception type in this situation. We'll consider fixing it in the release after VS2010.

Comment: Hmm, interesting that it's only those four. I guess that solves that then, I'll just have to use a different format. Thanks for this!

Comment: I really wonder why `Format16bppArgb1555` is included in that list. It's perfectly convertible to normal 1-byte-per-component color formats.